# Adding encoded image to twitter card

Tags: php, twitter

If I have an article with image encoded with base_64 and embedded into text.

Something like this: https://www.grubbid.com/blog/7PB/Big-Ron-Eats-Austin

Is there any way it can be used for twitter card?

https://dev.twitter.com/cards/types/summary-large-image

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I need to get a string that looks something like this: <meta name="twitter:image" content="http://example.com/images/articleimg.jpg"> assuming I was able to extract <img> with all base64 data in it, where will I put it? Content? I just need some starting point.

Comment: That's right. You need to save the image to your webserver.  Then you edit that tag so it points to the right location.